# Python Telegram Bot. Как узнать id последнего сообщения бота и id чата и передать их в другие функции?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Как мне получить необходимые данные , chat_id и message_id, чтобы в функции create_time_zones_keyboard() изменить сообщение от бота , которое было отправлено в функции wishes_command(message) ?

```
 def create_time_zones_keyboard():
     '''some code'''

     keyboard.append(кнопки)
     bot.edit_message_text(text="something text", 
                      chat_id='',
                      message_id='', 
                      reply_markup=keyboard)

def wishes_answer_keyboard():

    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button_1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='1',
                                    callback_data=create_time_zones_keyboard())
    button_2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='2', 
                                    callback_data=cancel_answer())

    return keyboard.add(button_yes, button_no)

@bot.message_handler(['wishes'])
def wishes_command(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 
                     "Some text", 
                     reply_markup=wishes_answer_keyboard())
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде так должно сработать

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: True)
def create_time_zones_keyboard(c):
 '''some code'''

 keyboard.append(кнопки)
 bot.edit_message_text(text="something text", 
                  chat_id=c.message.chat.id,
                  message_id=c.message.message_id, 
                  reply_markup=keyboard)
```